# gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.hive The property [proxy.port] must have an integer value

Tags: hive, google-cloud-platform, hiveql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have Hive table created on Google Cloud Dataproc, while executing below SQL query I am getting exception like this:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster mycluster \
    -e "select * from table limit 10;"

ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.hive)
  The property [proxy.port] must have an integer value: []
```

Comment: Hello @Dastagiri, your issue seems similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624539/google-cloud-sdk-installation-failed-proxy-port), and could be a networking issue.To isolate the issue, have you tried from [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) in the console?

Comment: Thank you , there is port number is missed in  configuration file i added the port number now it is working fine...